# Two input file types at the same time in GNU parallel?

Tags: pdf, parallel-processing, ocr, tesseract

Is it possible to have two input file types at the same time using one instance of [`gnu parallel`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)?

This long command:

```
find . -name \*.pdf | parallel -j 4 --progress --eta 'mkdir -p {.} && gs -dQUIET -dINTERPOLATE -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook -dNumRenderingThreads=4 -sDEVICE=pgmraw -r300 -dTextAlphaBits=4 -sProcessColorModel=DeviceGray -sColorConversionStrategy=Gray -dOverrideICC -o {.}/{.}-%03d.pgm {}' && time find . -name \*.pgm | parallel -j 4 --progress --eta 'tesseract {} {.} -l deu_frak && rm {.}.pgm'
```

a)

- creates a folder for each pdf it reads (first input file type)
- convert the pdf with `Ghostscript` to pgm images
- moves them in the respective folder
- then it would use tesseract to perform OCR on each pgm (second input file type)
- after which it save text files in each respective folder
- and finally, deletes all pgm image files.

However, the above command actually consists of two commands combined with `&&`, splitting the above routine into two separate parts. The result is that it would:

b)

1. convert first all pdfs into pgm image files (which eat up a lot of disk
   space!)
2. before it would start with ocr and a subsequent purge of the then
   unneeded pgm image files.

This is undesired, as it would eat up all my disk space before the second part of the command would execute!

Is is possible to combine both commands to one, so that `parallel` would go through the whole process of a) for the first four pdfs (as `parallel` does 4 jobs at the same time `-j 4`), before going to the next four pdf files?

However, it seems that something like the below minimal example is not possible with `parallel`:

```
parallel -j 4 --progress --eta 'mkdir -p {.} && gs -sDEVICE=pgmraw -r300 -o {.}/{.}-%03d.pgm {}' && tesseract {} {.} -l deu_frak && rm {.}.pgm’ ::: *.pdf *.pgm
```

Note, the two input file extensions `::: *.pdf *.pgm` at the end.

What can I do to make `parallel` follow routine a)?

**EDIT:**

This is the entire code I have tried as proposed by Ole Tange:

```
generate_pgm() {
  PDF="$1"
  find . -name \*.pdf | parallel 'mkdir -p {.} && gs -dQUIET -dINTERPOLATE -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook -dNumRenderingThreads=4 -sDEVICE=pgmraw -r300 -dTextAlphaBits=4 -sProcessColorModel=DeviceGray -sColorConversionStrategy=Gray -dOverrideICC -o {.}/{.}-%03d.pgm {}' ::: *.pdf
}
export -f generate_pgm
ocr() {
  PGM="$1"
  find . -name \*.pgm | parallel 'tesseract {} {.} -l deu_frak && rm {.}.pgm'
  rm "$PGM"
}
export -f ocr

time parallel -j 4 --progress --eta 'generate_pgm {}; parallel --argsep ,,, ocr ,,, pgm/*.pgm'  ::: *pdf
```

Unfortunately, it has been unsuccessful as this script would basically do the same as my original script. It would create folders of all PDF and start converting all PDF to PGM while starting the OCR on the first PGM images, instead of going through the all process for each four PDF before starting with the next four.

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 solutions:

```
generate_pgm() {
  PDF="$1"
  # gs stuff
}
export -f generate_pgm
ocr() {
  PGM="$1"
  # tesseract stuff
  rm "$PGM"
}
export -f ocr

parallel 'generate_pgm {}; parallel --argsep ,,, ocr ,,, pgm/*.pgm'  ::: *pdf
```

This will process a file completely before going to the next.

It will, however, run up to N^2 processes (N=number of cores). To avoid that use `--load`:

```
parallel 'generate_pgm {}; parallel --load 100% --argsep ,,, ocr ,,, pgm/*.pgm'  ::: *pdf
```

This way you should only get one active process per CPU core.

If you want it to only convert one PDF at a time:

```
parallel -j1 'generate_pgm {}; parallel --argsep ,,, ocr ,,, pgm/*.pgm'  ::: *pdf
```

Another solution is to use the dir processor https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-GNU-Parallel-as-dir-processor:

```
nice parallel generate_pgm ::: *pdf &
inotifywait -qmre MOVED_TO -e CLOSE_WRITE --format %w%f pgm_output_dir |   parallel ocr
```

This way the the pgm-generation will be done in parallel. The risk here is that if the pgm-generation is much faster than the ocr, it will still fill your disk.

Comment: Thank you, Ole Tange, for your reply. I have tried solution 1 with the above written command. However, the script would not wait for each process to be complete, but go simple ahead with the conversion of PDF to PGM. Do I overlook something?

Comment: See edit for a solution that one converts 1 at a time.

Comment: Hi Ole Tange, unfortunately the edit of the script does not function either. It would not go beyond the conversion of PDF to PGM. No OCR is done. In addition, it tells me `rm: pgm/*.pgm: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Maybe the solution lies in how to let parallel find only 4 PDF at a time, like `for file in $(ls | grep -E "\.pdf$" | tail -4); do … ; done`. But I cannot get it together. The issue would be to write a loop that we show parallel only 4 PDFs at a time.